# Problem with ListContourPlot feeding data format and WeatherData

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, curated-data, geography

With following code I am trying to show the mean wind speed patterns for a few geographic locations.

```
cords = Select[ 
           Reverse[CityData[#, "Coordinates"]] & /@ {"Oslo", "Vadso","Hammerfest"}, 
           Head@# == List &
        ]; 
ListContourPlot[
  Join @@ {#,List@WeatherData[#,
                              "MeanWindSpeed", 
                              {{2013, 1, 25}, {2013, 5, 1}, "Day"}
                  ][[1,2]]} & /@ cords
]
```

How can I improve the code to solve following problems:

1. Even if the requested date window is wider (a few days), it only takes one day data from `WeatherData` and when I am changing the partitioning part to `[[All,2]]` the plot doesn't work and says the format it wrong.
2. For even wider data range (a few years), there are some missing data for some days. How can I also filter that bad data in the code?

Remember, I need them exactly on the geographic location no  matter how wide my data range is.

Comment: This kind of questions don't show a real interest in learning the language. You're throwing in a whole problem's coding and asking for a solution. Perhaps you should break it up in pieces, and ask about your doubts. Neither of your questions are related to a Plotting problem.

Comment: 1) Your `[[1,2]]` takes the first windspeed from every location. So, it doesn't help to increase the data range. 2. `[[All,2]]` results in passing a list of windspeeds for every location to `ListContourPlot`. However, `ListContourPlot` expects a single dependent value for each point not a list. How would you interpret that? You need to apply `Mean` on that list to get a single, average value. 3) You can delete `Missing[...]` data points using `DeleteCases`.

Comment: @belisarius with many thanks for your previous hint; but frankly I am struggling with this language for around two days. I have to admit that it was very constructive hint of you and made me to look a the  `Join` and  `List` functionality thoroughly.I advanced the code considerably and knew the`ListContourPlot` better now but those problems are really hindering me of any progress.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries manay thanks for advices but I don't want to make `mean`. It is very easy to make mean of those data.But I need the `ListContourPlot` to make the plot based on the all recorded data?I need the intensity of colors based on the analysis of previous data. Is it possible?

Comment: Using the Mean *is* making use of all recorded data. I'm afraid you are being rather unclear here. What do you want `ListContourPlot` to show on each location based on that set of windspeeds? You need a single color there. So, what should that depict?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries you are right.It seems that I am expecting too much of `ListContourPlot`. I wanted to include the probability of data on it but seems if I want to variate something, I have to change different scenarios.For example for different months .Many thanks

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Something very strange happening here!!I added "Bodo" to the cities.The mean of all years MeanSpeedData is 22 for this city but it shows in the `ListContourPlot` 8.How it could happen?!!!This is really bothering me?!!!

Comment: @belisarius Something very strange happening here!!I added "Bodo" to the cities.The mean of all years MeanSpeedData is 22 for this city but it shows in the ListContourPlot 8.How it could happen?!!!This is really bothering me?!!!Any help please?

Comment: That's because you used `Reverse` to get your coordinates. That's OK for plotting, but not for getting information from WeatherData, which expects latlong, not longlat.

Comment: @YEP that means I am reading other place info instead of my requested location!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your `[[1,2]]` takes the first windspeed from every location. So, it doesn't help to increase the data range.
2. `[[All,2]]` results in passing a list of windspeeds for every location to `ListContourPlot`. However, `ListContourPlot` expects a single dependent value for each point not a list. How would you interpret that? You need to apply `Mean` on that list to get a single, average value.
3. You can delete `Missing[...]` data points using `DeleteCases`.

Something like the following should work:

```
ListContourPlot[
 Append[#,
    Mean[
     DeleteCases[
      WeatherData[
        #,
        "MeanWindSpeed",
        {{2013, 1, 25}, {2013, 5, 1}, "Day"}
        ][[All, 2]],
      Missing["NotAvailable"]
      ]
     ]
    ] & /@ cords
 ]
```

[image]

If I were you, I'd increase the number of locations in the plot. As it is, it looks rather boring.

Comment: manay thanks for advices but I don't want to make mean. It is very easy to make mean of those data.But I need the ListContourPlot to make the plot based on the all recorded data?I need the intensity of colors based on the analysis of previous data. Is it possible?